# pyQGIS 2.0: Sending signal when identify button is pressed via gui

Tags: qgis, python

I have a question regarding the qgis identify tool for version 2.0. I would like to know if it's possible to send a signal when the actionIdentify is triggered by the user via the gui.

I'm trying to call a python function within a plugin if this action is triggered.

I've tried two different ways so far with no success:

1)

```
def initGui(self):
    ...
    self.iface.actionIdentify().triggered()
    self.idTool = self.canvas.mapTool()

def myFunction(self):
    if self.canvas.mapTool() == self.idTool:
        QgsMessageBox.information(None, 'Info', 'Tool is IdentifyTool')
        self.anotherFunction()

def anotherFunction(self):
    QgsMessageBox.information(None, 'Info', 'Successful connection')
```

This gives no error, but the QgsMessageBoxes don't show up, thus I am not successfully connecting to the function. It's also problematic, because my way of setting the idTool parameter is by first triggering the tool. This means that even if everything runs as I thought it would, the if statement would always be true, as the self.canvas.mapTool() would surely be the idTool.

this gives me a PyQt4.QtGui.QAction object:

```
idTool = qgis.utils.iface.actionIdentify()
```

this gives me a qgis.gui.QgsMapToolIdentify object:

```
qgis.utils.iface.actionIdentify().trigger()
anotherIDTool = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().mapTool()
```

I can't successfully compare the former with my current map tool as returned from mapCanvas().mapTool(). However, I don't want to have to trigger the tool first to get the proper object.

2)

```
def __init__(self, iface):
    ...
    self.idTool = QgsMapToolIdentify(self.canvas)
    ...

def initGui(self):
    ...
    self.idTool.mapToolSet.connect(self.myFunction)

def myFunction(self):
    currentTool = self.canvas.mapTool()
    if currentTool == self.idTool:
        self.anotherFunction
```

My problem here is that the two QgsMapToolIdentify parameters point to different object numbers, so I never get past my if statement. What am I missing about the way these QgsMapToolIdentify objects are named?

**UPDATE** I am revisiting this issue for QGIS 2.8. Does anyone have any ideas?